# Use the package of a flavor in the manifest

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Given the following flavors for an app:

```
productFlavors {
    pro {
        applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.pro"
    }
    free {
        applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.free"
    }
}
```

And I need to declare the GCM permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<application ...>
    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
</application>
```

Where the `com.example.gcm´`must be replaced with `com.example.my.pkg.pro` or `com.example.my.pkg.free` depending on the current flavor.

How can I configure my manifest to automatically pick the package defined in the `applicationId` field?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use placeholders:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.commonsware.android.gcm.client"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

  <permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="GCMBroadcastReceiverCompat"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    </application>
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Push/GCMClient2))

Here, you will see `${applicationId}` used as a placeholder. This should automatically expand to be the `applicationId` of the flavor that you are building.